# Error Unknown variable:BouncingAtomsMorph openInWorld please correct or cancel

Tags: pharo

I'm new to Pharo ,my problem is when I try to run the BouncingAtomsMorph openInWorld example I keep getting the following error message:

> Unknown variable:BouncingAtomsMorph openInWorld please correct or cancel

Please help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sadly Bouncing Atoms are no longer included in the standard distribution of newer Pharo versions.

To load it evaluate in a workspace or playground:

```
Gofer it 
     url: 'http://smalltalkhub.com/mc/PharoExtras/MorphExamplesAndDemos/main';
     package: 'MorphExamplesAndDemos';
     load.
```

Then

```
BouncingAtomsMorph new openInWorld
```

will work.

---

**Pharo 5 update:**

The `MorphExamplesAndDemos` package does no longer load correctly starting with Pharo 5. As [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41084128/2012262), you can still look at the `BouncingAtomsMorph` by just clicking on ***Abandon*** when a debugger message tells you that this message is no longer understood (It's a problem with another example in the same package):

> FileList class>>registerFileReader

Comment: You’re welcome. Don’t hesitate to ask other Pharo and Smalltalk questions on Stackoverflow. There are a bunch of Pharo programmers here to give answers. If you like the answer above, consider *accepting* it by clicking on the check mark beside the answer.