# BouncingAtomsMorph new openInWorld in pharo

Tags: pharo

When I try to run the BouncingAtomsMorph new openInWorld in my playground, I find a message saying that the variable is unknown.

Comment: This was asked before, the answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26197639/2012262

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are reading Pharo by example. Just skip the section about BouncingAtomsMorph